# UIDocumentInteractionController does not open PDF, txt etc

Tags: ios, ios8, xamarin, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to implement UIDocumentInteractionController to show previous of some file in my app. The problem is that any files I checked so far PDFs, txts, docs etc. is not shown. The issue is that I can see UIDocumentInteractionController showing up, but the only thing I see is "Loading..." and spinning dialog. What is even more weird PNG files are loaded correctly and show up immediately.

I am using Xamarin.iOS (the newest stable release) and iOS 8.1.1.

Any of you has an idea why is that happening?